# Lambda as default argument of templated function

Tags: c++

Lambda specified as default value for templated function argument:

```
template<typename F>
void f(F g = []{})
{
    g();
}

int main() 
{
    f(); // a) ERROR: candidate template ignored: couldn't infer template argument 'F'
    f([]{}); // b) success
}
```

1. Why compiler doesn't have a problem of inferring template argument `F` in case (b) but fails in case (a)?
2. If this is not supported by standard, why lambda as default argument compiles at all?
3. I wouldn't like to use `std::function` here and I'm trying to avoid overloading, is this possible?